# Convert text file that contains colon to json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Existing Code

```
import json
filename = 'thunar-volman/debian/control'
dict1 = {}
with open(filename) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        print(line)
        command, description = line.strip().split(': ')
        print(command)
        print(description)
        dict1[command.strip()] = description.strip()

with open("test.json", "w") as out_file:
    json.dump(dict1, out_file, indent=4, sort_keys = False)
```

Error

```
Build-Depends
debhelper-compat (= 13),
               intltool,

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read.py", line 7, in <module>
    command, description = line.strip().split(': ')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

The text file I am intending to process to json is here - https://salsa.debian.org/xfce-team/goodies/thunar-volman/-/blob/debian/master/debian/control

How can I process the content such that the content behind the colon of `Build-Depends` would be processed as the `description` for the `Build-Depends` `command`.

Any help would be very much appreciated as I am very new to json.

Comment: How do you want to handle lines that do not have a colon, for example the nine lines following the Build-Depends line?

Comment: You can't assume that every line you read is a `key: value` pair. At a brief glance, you have to check each line for leading whitespace: if there is any, then the line is a continuation of the value on the previous line(s), not a new key/value pair.

Comment: You need to account for (at least) two things. 1) blank lines 2) lines that do not contain ': '

Comment: (Conversely, you cannot assume a line *with* a colon is a complete key/value pair, either. You have to assume that the value may continue on to the following line until you confirm the next line is not indented.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `maxsplit` of [Python String split() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp).

```py
from pathlib import Path
import json


with Path('control').open() as file:   # be sure to adjust your path
    commands, description = {}, ''
    for line in file:
        if not line.strip(): continue  # if line is blank continue loop
        if ':' in line:
            # use 'maxsplit=1' to split only the first occurance of ':'
            command, description = list(map(str.strip, line.split(':', maxsplit=1)))
        else:
            # if not ':' in line append line to description
            description += ' %s' % line.strip()
        commands[command] = description

with Path('test.json') as file: file.write_text(json.dumps(commands, indent=4))
```

output:

```json
{
    "Source": "thunar-volman",
    "Section": "xfce",
    "Priority": "optional",
    "Maintainer": "Debian Xfce Maintainers <debian-xfce@lists.debian.org>",
    "Uploaders": "Yves-Alexis Perez <corsac@debian.org>",
    "Build-Depends": "debhelper-compat (= 13), intltool, libexo-2-dev, libgtk-3-dev, libgudev-1.0-dev, libnotify-dev, libxfce4ui-2-dev, libxfce4util-dev, libxfconf-0-dev, xfce4-dev-tools (>= 4.16)",
    "Rules-Requires-Root": "no",
    "Standards-Version": "4.6.1",
    "Vcs-Git": "https://salsa.debian.org/xfce-team/goodies/thunar-volman.git",
    "Vcs-Browser": "https://salsa.debian.org/xfce-team/goodies/thunar-volman",
    "Homepage": "https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/thunar-volman",
    "Package": "thunar-volman",
    "Architecture": "linux-any",
    "Depends": "exo-utils, thunar, ${misc:Depends}, ${shlibs:Depends}",
    "Description": "Thunar extension for volumes management The Thunar Volume Manager is an extension for the Thunar file manager, which enables automatic management of removable drives and media."
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your file i'ts yaml

For work with yaml files you need library ruamel.yaml

**Install**

```
pip install ruamel.yaml
```

**Load file and convert to json and write json**

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
import json
yaml=YAML(typ='safe')   # default, if not specfied, is 'rt' (round-trip)
filename = 'thunar-volman/debian/control'
dict1 = {}
with open(filename) as fh:
    dict1 = yaml.load(filename)
with open("test.json", "w") as out_file:
    json.dump(dict1, out_file, indent=4, sort_keys = False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
import json
filename = 'thunar-volman/debian/control'
dict1 = {}
command = ""
description = ""
with open(filename) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        print(line)
        if line[0] == " ":
            description = line.strip()
            dict1[command.strip()].append(description.strip())
        else:
            command, description = line.strip().split(': ')
            dict1[command.strip()] = description.strip()

with open("test.json", "w") as out_file:
    json.dump(dict1, out_file, indent=4, sort_keys = False)
```

So basically if there is a white space in the start then it is going to append in the previous command, the new item.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file and read it line by line. Ignore blank lines. Split on colon checking number of tokens. Ensure sanity of the input data

```
from json import dumps

CONTROL = '/Volumes/G-Drive/control'

jdata = {}

with open(CONTROL) as control:
    previous_key = None
    for line in control:
        if len(sline := line.strip()) > 0: # make sure to skip blank lines
            if line[0].isspace():
                if previous_key is not None:
                    # you may not want the newline prefix
                    jdata[previous_key] += '\n' + sline
                else:
                    raise ValueError('Line has leading whitespace but no previous keyword')
            elif len(tokens := sline.split(':', 1)) == 2: # note second argument to split()
                # looks like a normal keyword and value
                key, value = tokens
                jdata[key] = value.lstrip()
                previous_key = key
            else:
                raise ValueError(f'Cannot understand "{line.rstrip()}"')

print(dumps(jdata, indent=2))
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "Source": "thunar-volman",
  "Section": "xfce",
  "Priority": "optional",
  "Maintainer": "Debian Xfce Maintainers <debian-xfce@lists.debian.org>",
  "Uploaders": "Yves-Alexis Perez <corsac@debian.org>",
  "Build-Depends": "debhelper-compat (= 13),\nintltool,\nlibexo-2-dev,\nlibgtk-3-dev,\nlibgudev-1.0-dev,\nlibnotify-dev,\nlibxfce4ui-2-dev,\nlibxfce4util-dev,\nlibxfconf-0-dev,\nxfce4-dev-tools (>= 4.16)",
  "Rules-Requires-Root": "no",
  "Standards-Version": "4.6.1",
  "Vcs-Git": "https://salsa.debian.org/xfce-team/goodies/thunar-volman.git",
  "Vcs-Browser": "https://salsa.debian.org/xfce-team/goodies/thunar-volman",
  "Homepage": "https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/thunar-volman",
  "Package": "thunar-volman",
  "Architecture": "linux-any",
  "Depends": "exo-utils, thunar, ${misc:Depends}, ${shlibs:Depends}",
  "Description": "Thunar extension for volumes management\nThe Thunar Volume Manager is an extension for the Thunar file manager, which\nenables automatic management of removable drives and media."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is very simple, I wrote working code for it in under five minutes, in one go.

You have some lines representing a mapping, the lines can contain colons and a line that contains a colon indicates the start of a new key value pair.

The key is on the left side of the colon and the value can span multiple lines.

We can assign a variable named `key`, set it to initially `None`. We then loop through the lines, for each line, if we found a colon and the first character is not space, we have found a new key value pair.

We add the previous key value pair to the dictionary if key is not `None`. We then set the current key value pair to be remembered, and use them in later iterations.

And then if the line is not empty and not the start of a new pair, it is the continuation of the previous value, we add it to the previous value.

In this way we can process all items correctly, but we will miss the last item.

We can add it later.

Code:

```
import json

lines = """Source: thunar-volman
Section: xfce
Priority: optional
Maintainer: Debian Xfce Maintainers <debian-xfce@lists.debian.org>
Uploaders: Yves-Alexis Perez <corsac@debian.org>
Build-Depends: debhelper-compat (= 13),
               intltool,
               libexo-2-dev,
               libgtk-3-dev,
               libgudev-1.0-dev,
               libnotify-dev,
               libxfce4ui-2-dev,
               libxfce4util-dev,
               libxfconf-0-dev,
               xfce4-dev-tools (>= 4.16)
Rules-Requires-Root: no
Standards-Version: 4.6.1
Vcs-Git: https://salsa.debian.org/xfce-team/goodies/thunar-volman.git
Vcs-Browser: https://salsa.debian.org/xfce-team/goodies/thunar-volman
Homepage: https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/thunar-volman

Package: thunar-volman
Architecture: linux-any
Depends: exo-utils, thunar, ${misc:Depends}, ${shlibs:Depends}
Description: Thunar extension for volumes management
 The Thunar Volume Manager is an extension for the Thunar file manager, which
 enables automatic management of removable drives and media.
""".splitlines()

key = None
dic = {}
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    if ':' in line and line[0] != ' ':
        if key:
            dic[key] = cache[0] if len(cache) == 1 else cache
        key, cache = line.split(':', 1)
        key, cache = key.strip(), [cache.strip()]
    elif line:
        cache.append(line)

dic[key] = cache[0] if len(cache) == 1 else cache
print(json.dumps(dic, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
```

```
{
    "Source": "thunar-volman",
    "Section": "xfce",
    "Priority": "optional",
    "Maintainer": "Debian Xfce Maintainers <debian-xfce@lists.debian.org>",
    "Uploaders": "Yves-Alexis Perez <corsac@debian.org>",
    "Build-Depends": [
        "debhelper-compat (= 13),",
        "intltool,",
        "libexo-2-dev,",
        "libgtk-3-dev,",
        "libgudev-1.0-dev,",
        "libnotify-dev,",
        "libxfce4ui-2-dev,",
        "libxfce4util-dev,",
        "libxfconf-0-dev,",
        "xfce4-dev-tools (>= 4.16)"
    ],
    "Rules-Requires-Root": "no",
    "Standards-Version": "4.6.1",
    "Vcs-Git": "https://salsa.debian.org/xfce-team/goodies/thunar-volman.git",
    "Vcs-Browser": "https://salsa.debian.org/xfce-team/goodies/thunar-volman",
    "Homepage": "https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/thunar-volman",
    "Package": "thunar-volman",
    "Architecture": "linux-any",
    "Depends": "exo-utils, thunar, ${misc:Depends}, ${shlibs:Depends}",
    "Description": [
        "Thunar extension for volumes management",
        "The Thunar Volume Manager is an extension for the Thunar file manager, which",
        "enables automatic management of removable drives and media."
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re` (`text` contains the string from your question) ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/PXKUuy/2)):

```py
import re

out = dict(re.findall(r"^(\S+):\s*(.*?)(?=^\S*:|\Z)", text, flags=re.M | re.S))
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "Source": "thunar-volman\n",
    "Section": "xfce\n",
    "Priority": "optional\n",
    "Maintainer": "Debian Xfce Maintainers <debian-xfce@lists.debian.org>\n",
    "Uploaders": "Yves-Alexis Perez <corsac@debian.org>\n",
    "Build-Depends": "debhelper-compat (= 13),\n               intltool,\n               libexo-2-dev,\n               libgtk-3-dev,\n               libgudev-1.0-dev,\n               libnotify-dev,\n               libxfce4ui-2-dev,\n               libxfce4util-dev,\n               libxfconf-0-dev,\n               xfce4-dev-tools (>= 4.16)\n",
    "Rules-Requires-Root": "no\n",
    "Standards-Version": "4.6.1\n",
    "Vcs-Git": "https://salsa.debian.org/xfce-team/goodies/thunar-volman.git\n",
    "Vcs-Browser": "https://salsa.debian.org/xfce-team/goodies/thunar-volman\n",
    "Homepage": "https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/thunar-volman\n\n",
    "Package": "thunar-volman\n",
    "Architecture": "linux-any\n",
    "Depends": "exo-utils, thunar, ${misc:Depends}, ${shlibs:Depends}\n",
    "Description": "Thunar extension for volumes management\n The Thunar Volume Manager is an extension for the Thunar file manager, which\n enables automatic management of removable drives and media.",
}
```